# Why is MIME::Lite->new() is not working in my server?

Tags: perl, compatibility, mail-server

I have the following code to mail

```
#!perl
use MIME::Lite;
open (LOG_FILE, '>Mail_Log.txt');
print LOG_FILE "  creating mail\n";
    $msg = MIME::Lite->new(
    From =>'me@mine.com',
    To =>'me@mine.com',
    Subject =>'Congrats',
    Data =>"some messgae."
);
print LOG_FILE "  attaching to mail\n";
$msg->attach
(
    Type=>'TEXT',
Path=>'Log.txt',
Filename=>'log File.txt',
    Disposition => 'attachment'
);
print LOG_FILE "  sending the mail\n";
$msg->send( "smtp", "mailout.server.com" );
print "message sent successfully";
print LOG_FILE "  mail sent\n";
```

The above code works fine in my local. :)
I am able to send and receive mails.

I converted this Perl(.pl) file executable(.exe) using PerlPackager(pp), and transferred this to my windows server where it should actually perform the function. But the execution is stopping after

```
print LOG_FILE "  creating mail\n";
```

As i can see the log written on to the Mail_Log.txt.

Help me in solving this.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: This should really be a comment: The MIME::Lite doc suggests to not use it at all but also mentions that it uses defaults methods for your OS. So it may be that the packager creates a non-portable version if compiling on a different OS than what you run it on. Does the compiled version run on your local system? Could you compile on the same OS it is supposed to run on later?

Comment: @DeVadder, He's not using the default mailing method; he explicitly stated to use SMTP and provided the server.

Comment: What does `->last_send_successful` return?

Comment: @ikegami Oh i see, that only means the sending method? Makes sense. Then it would not apply anyways as it apparently hangs long before the sending. My bad.

Comment: @DeVadder yes.. you are correct... the compiled version is not working in the local compiled machine also .... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say you have any error messages but this thread may be helpful: [Missing MIME\types.db from pp-generated code](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=91530)

Comment: Yeah @gangabass This worked for me...  **pp -a "C:\strawberry\cpan\build\MIME-Types-2.04-D8k10V\lib\MIME\types.db;lib/MIME/types.db" -F PatchContent=MIME/Types.pm -M PerlIO::encoding -o mailer.exe mailer.pl**